# Create one form with multiple pages?

Tags: forms, visual-studio, visual-c++

Whats the best way to make multiple pages in one form? For example, when someone enters password, the whole scene will be deleted and the second page will be opened with search bars and stuff.... But I also want to be available to design second form. Whats the best way to do it? Thanks :).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: And what should I do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e(v=vs.110).aspx
Try using MDI concept.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. 
Do you want multiple pages active in a form at runtime? If yes, change the “Window style,” “Modal,” and “Hide on Exit” properties of called window accordingly.
Or do you want multiple forms active at a time? If yes, use OPEN_FORM built-in when you call another form.
If neither of above is your requirement, elaborate in detail.